# Can I remove one field from mongoDB document after some time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have user mongoose Schema like bellow

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
login: {
    type: String
},
email: {
    type: String
},
password: {
    type: String
},
tokens: [
    {
        access: {
            type: String
        },
        token: {
            type: String,
        }
    }
],
});
```

I want to remove single token object, after some time, for example 30s.  If I add createAt field with expires property

```
tokens: [
    {
        access: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        createdAt: {type:Date,default:Date.now,expires:10}
    }
],
```

Then the result: all document is removed. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a post save hook.
First create a childSchema for the tokens:

```
ChildTokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema(    {
    access: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {type:Date,default:Date.now,expires:10}
});
```

Add a post-save hook on the childModel with a setTimeout:

```
ChildTokenSchema.post('save', function(doc) {
 if (doc.createdAt && doc.createdAt.expires ) {
  setTimeout(doc.remove(), doc.createdAt.expires * 1000)
 }
});
```

Modify your parent schema:

```
....
....
tokens: [ChildTokenSchema]
....
```